# Replace empty strings on argparse to None

Tags: python, argparse

I am using groovy to call a python class, I am defaulting to None the empty arguments, but I am finding lots of problems to default to None null or empty strings ('') also.

I hope there would be something in `argparse` to check if the argument is '' and change it to None in that case so further in the code I don't have to check for `None` and for '' just check if is not `None`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) argument of `ArgumentParser.add_argument()` is a function that "allows any necessary type-checking and type conversions to be performed." You can abuse this:

```
import argparse

def nullable_string(val):
    if not val:
        return None
    return val

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=nullable_string)
print(parser.parse_args(['--foo', ''])
```

Output:

```
Namespace(foo=None)
```

Comment: thanks @JETM, works like a charm and is what I was looking for. I found a more tedious way: 
inside a for loop adding : vars(arguments)[arg] = None if vars(arguments)[arg] is ' ' else vars(arguments)[arg]. 
Which is very ugly, thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

Specify the command line argument as having type `str` with default `None`, for example:

```
parser.add_argument('-j', '--jfile', default=None, type=str)
```

Then if the user omits `-j` entirely then you will get `None` back. But if the user puts `-j` on the command line with nothing after it, they will get the error *argument -j/--jfile: expected one argument* and they will have to supply a string value to get past this. So you should always get either `None` or a non-empty string.

Comment: Explicitly supplying an empty string, i.e. `-j ''`, will still set the `jfile` argument to an empty string in this case.

Comment: Any empty string is still "falsey" so doing a conditional check like "if not args.j: return" would still work